# Converting files from service to PDF

Tags: javascript, java, pdf, liferay

I am converting a byte array I got from the service to a pdf and displays it in a window pop up using JS.

```
Map<String, Object> serviceMap = new HashMap<>();

// assigning map service value to serviceMap
// with key "bytes" that holds the byte array and key "disposition" that holds the filename

byte[] byteArray = (byte[]) serviceMap.get("bytes");
String contentDisposition = serviceMap.get("disposition").toString();

response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setContentLength(byteArray.length);
response.setProperty(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, contentDisposition);      

OutputStream os = null;

    try {
        os = response.getPortletOutputStream();
        os.write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
        os.close();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
            //
    }
```

JS:

```
window.open(url, "popupWindow");
```

This works fine if the file type I get from the service is a pdf file (checking it from contentDisposition). But it will failed to load if its a jpg.

My question is, how can I convert any file type like jpg to pdf first so I can display it correctly on the pop up window screen? Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't you rather check the file's format and set the Content-Type accordingly?

Comment: @ChrisG - you mean if the contentDisposition is a jpg then I'll set the content type to jpg? But i don't think it will be displayed as a pdf file.

Comment: Do you serve an `image/jpeg` with `Content-Type` set to `application/pdf`?

Comment: @guest271314 - It'll failed to load as a pdf if I do that. That's why I wanted it to convert to pdf first before displaying it as a pdf.

Comment: If you do what? If the byte array from service is a `.jpeg` file why do you set `Content-Type` to `application/pdf`?

Comment: @guest271314 - I'm asking if the file I get from the service can be converted to a pdf file so that I can display it as a pdf file. If I set it to content type jpg then it will be displayed as a jpg file, right?

Comment: Convert the byte array to a `pdf` at the server

Comment: The question here is, why on earth would you convert a perfectly fine jpg to a PDF just to display it? Why not simply send it as `image/jpeg`?

Comment: @ChrisG - if there's a scenario like uploading any file type then the user wants to view it as a pdf file. Is it a bad idea? If it is, then is it recommend to check each file type uploaded so you can set the content type align with the file type uploaded?

Comment: Again, where are you getting this from? Why would a user want to view an image as PDF? Plus, even if the user can upload any file type, how are you realistically going to turn all of them into PDFs? You'd need a conversion mechanism for each individual file type, in which case you need to *check the file type first*, anyway.